# Unable to load server on local host

Tags: node.js

When I attempt to run my node.js script on a port on my localhost, the page just tries to load forever, but doesn't display what it should.  Is this just do to the fact that my computer cannot handle running the script?  If so how would this be solved for testing purposes.

```
    // setup express to configure a basic web server
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();

 // moment.js is the preferred date library
 var moment = require('moment');

 // access Node.js Crypto library for signature generation
 var crypto = require('crypto');

 // use request or request-promise to call into STATS API
 var request = require('request');

 // respond to all get requests
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   // get the current time
   var timeFromEpoch = moment.utc().unix();

   // set the API key (this is the actual key)
   var apiKey = 'key';

   // set the shared secret key (actual shared secret hash key)
   var secret = 'secret';

   // generate signature
   var sig = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(apiKey + secret + timeFromEpoch).digest('hex');

   request('api:website',
       function (err, response, body) {
         // parse the body as JSON
         var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
         res.json(parsedBody);
       });
 });

 var port = 3001;
 app.listen(port, function () {
   console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

 // run this file (node [filename]) and go to http://127.0.0.1:3001
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Also code?

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva I have added the code with certain information omitted, but it is just API information

Comment: Is there any error emitted from client or server?

Comment: @huachengzan there is no error, it just attempts to load continuously, but nothing ever shows up.